# Deconstruct tuple for pattern matching

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

Given a function `async Task<(Boolean result, MyObject value)> TryGetAsync()`, I can do

```
if((await TryGetAsync()) is var ret && ret.result)
{
    //use ret.value
}
```

But if I try to use declare the types or use deconstruction get an error "a declaration is not allowed in this context":

```
//declaration. error
if((await TryGetAsync()) is (Boolean result, MyObject value) ret && ret.result)
{
    //use ret.value
}

//deconstruction, also error.
if((await TryGetAsync()) is (Boolean result, MyObject value) && result)
{
    //use value
}
```

How can I avoid using the first option `var ret` in this scenario? My issue with this is that the types are not evident (which is a separate discussion).

Comment: @Evk `out` parameters are not possible in async functions.

Comment: Indeed, forgot about that. Well, then `var` seems best option for now. I read somewhere in C# 8 they might support syntax you are after.

Comment: Maybe use generic type instead of named tuple as return value? All such `TryGet` functions follow the same pattern, so you might have `Result<T>` with `bool Success` and `T Value` type, then your match will be `if (await TryGetAsync() is Result<MyObject> res && res.Success)`

Comment: Yea I might end up doing that, at least for functions I can change. Feels like moving back in time though :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The pattern matching specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/patterns.md) doesn't allow the value tuple notation as a valid `type_pattern` in the pattern matching grammar.

The tuple notation is rewritten in the compiler to use `ValueTuple`. So there is an option: it does work with the underlying type, `ValueTuple<bool, MyObject>`:

```
if ((await TryGetAsync()) is ValueTuple<bool, MyObject> ret && ret.Item1)
```

While not ideal, it could provide you with a workaround.

Comment: Seems like a hole in the current spec. Thanks for the link, with this and Evk's suggestion I have some workarounds. Here's hoping it will be amended.

Comment: It is not a hole. The specification is just not written to cover every case. It costs huge amount of time to cover all possible paths.

Comment: Yes I didn't mean that it is an error in the spec, only that it feels like something that would blend in nicely and be worth covering.

Comment: That's true. There are many of such cases where the design team chose to cover the necessary, instead of the extended.

Answer (score 3):

In C# 8.0 you can use your last option and get no error:

```
if((await TryGetAsync()) is (Boolean result, MyObject value) && result)
{
    //use value
}
```